# Gradient estimate for convex function

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Consider $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a convex, twice differentiable function with the gradient $\nabla \varphi$ Lipschitz-continuous. Suppose the function achieve a minimum in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We can write the following gradient system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t) = -\nabla\varphi(x(t))\\
x(0) = x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
From a much more general case it is known that the following estimate is true:
\begin{equation}
\|\nabla \varphi(x(t))\|\leq \frac{C}{t}
\end{equation}
for a certain constant $C$. I would like to prove this inequality without using the general case, but I haven't found anything yet. How can I prove it?

Comment: Probably some assumption is missing. For example, in the case $\varphi(x) = x$ I do not see such gradient decay estimate.

Comment: Correct, the function must achieve a minimum in R^n